# Поиск лиц с помощью OpenCV на Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Нашёл код который мне нужен, но как я понял он для Python 2 .
Помогите переделать для Python 3 .

```
import sys
import cv,cv2
import numpy
cascade = cv.Load('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
c=1.6
Sr=15

def detect(image):
 bitmap = cv.fromarray(image)
 faces = cv.HaarDetectObjects(bitmap, cascade, cv.CreateMemStorage(0))
 if faces:
  for (x,y,w,h),n in faces:  
   k=float(w)/bitmap.cols
   S = Sr*c/k
   cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,255),3)
   cv2.putText(image,'S=%s'%(S),(x,y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0,(255,255,255))
 return image

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while 1:
        _,frame =cam.read()
        frame = numpy.asarray(detect(frame))
        cv2.imshow("features", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 0x1b: # ESC
            print 'ESC pressed. Exiting ...'
            break
```

проблема с модулем cv , как я понял в Python 3 его нету.

Comment: `print 'ESC pressed. Exiting ...'`
заменить на
`print ('ESC pressed. Exiting ...')`

Answer (score 3):

В современных версиях [OpenCV API немного поменялось](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html).

Пример поиска лиц на фотографии:

```
import cv2

url='http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/11/10/23/2E503F1500000578-3312647-image-a-39_1447197228350.jpg'

# читаем фото из интернета    
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
ret,img = cap.read()

cv2.imshow('img',img)
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

загружаем данные заранее натренированных классификаторов (поменяйте пути, чтобы они указывали на соответствующие XML файлы в вашем окружении):

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\py36\Library\etc\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\py36\Library\etc\haarcascades\haarcascade_eye.xml')
```

преобразовываем фото в оттенки серого:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

пытаемся найти лица и глаза на фото:

```
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
```

сохраняем результат:

```
cv2.imwrite(r'd:/temp/res.png', img)
```

получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: MaxU, Огромное спасибо , разобрался без проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы нарисовать рамки вокруг лиц (без глаз) на картинке:

```
def detect_faces(f_cascade, bgr_img, scale_factor=1.3):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # need grayscale image
    faces = f_cascade.detectMultiScale(  # detect faces
        gray, scaleFactor=scale_factor, minNeighbors=5)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:  # draw a rectangle around each face
        cv2.rectangle(bgr_img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    return len(faces)  # return the number of detected faces
```

где в качестве каскадного классификатора можно передать `haarcascade_frontalface_alt`, установленный вместе с opencv:

```
import os
import cv2  # $ pip install opencv-python

path = os.path.join(cv2.__path__[0], 'data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
assert os.path.exists(path)
haar_face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(path)
```

Чтобы нарисовать лица на картинке, заданной в командной строке:

```
import sys

bgr_img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
nfaces = detect_faces(haar_face_cascade, bgr_img, 1.05)
print(f'detected {nfaces}')  # -> 85

# show image
cv2.imshow('Image', img)
cv2.waitKey()  # wait until any key is pressed
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Результат для [фото с выставки](http://maxpixel.freegreatpicture.com/Human-Photo-Montage-Observer-Exhibition-Faces-2944065):

[image: detected faces haar]

Видно, что не все лица определились и есть ложные срабатывания. Увеличивая `scale_factor` уменьшается число ложных срабатываний и общее число обнаруженных лиц на картинке.

В качестве альтернативы можно использовать [LBP каскадные классификаторы из OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/lbpcascades), требующие меньше ресурсов, но у которых больше ложных срабатываний:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('lbpcascade_frontalface_improved.xml')
bgr_img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
nfaces = detect_faces(face_cascade, bgr_img, 1.01)
print(f'detected {nfaces}') # -> 99
cv2.imwrite('detected-faces-lbp.png', bgr_img)
```

[image: detected faces lbp]

Более точные результаты нежели LBP или Haar каскадные классификаторы из OpenCV, используя умеренные ресурсы (достаточно для видео), можно получить с помощью OpenCV `dnn` модуля. [Face detection with OpenCV and deep learning](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/02/26/face-detection-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/).