# Ошибка cv2.error

Tags: python, opencv

Когда я запускаю строку

```
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5)
```

(используется opencv-python 4.1.0), ничего не работает. Ошибка:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1658: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

У другого человека тот же код работает. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Может быть просто у него Мак, а у меня Винда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вы не указали полный путь к соответствующему XML: `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` или указали его неверно:

```
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'C:\<full_path_to...>\Library\etc\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

[Похожий вопрос на SO...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/782280/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-opencv-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-3)